# Spark based processing of data stored on SSD

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, solid-state-drive

We are currently using Spark 2.1 based application which analyses and process huge number of records to generate some stats which is used for report generation. Now our we are using 150 executors, 2 core per executor and 10 GB per executor for our spark jobs and size of data is ~3TB stored in parquet format. For processing 12 months of data it is taking ~15 mins of time.

Now to improve performance we want to try full SSD based node to store data in HDFS. Well the question is, are there any special configuration/optimisation to be done for SSD? Are there any study done for Spark processing performance on SSD based HDFS vs HDD based HDFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hardware-provisioning.html#local-disks

`SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` is config that you need to change.

https://www.slideshare.net/databricks/optimizing-apache-spark-throughput-using-intel-optane-and-intel-memory-drive-technology-with-ravikanth-durgavajhala

Use case is K means algo but will help.

Comment: if it solves your problem,you should accept the answer .

Comment: @Viplock I have accepted the answer for now. I was just waiting for some more pointers actually.